# User input login then continue directing through macros possible?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to run a macro that's end result would be landing on the page with the needed information after a series of searches. So far, my macro opens the webpage, but it requires the user to input their username and password. Would it be possible for the macro to open the webpage, then the user would manually enter their login info, and finally my macro would take over again and lead them to the correct results?

I feel comfortable being able to get them from the post-login screen to the results, but am stuck on the login page.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the user first enter username and password and other relevant info, then the macro contacts the webpage submits user & password and just continues.